# How to parse strings in a text file containing local variables using a Windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

Suppose there's a text file:

```
abc %x%
def %y%
```

and a batch file:

```
setlocal
set x=123
set y=456
for /f %%i in (textfile.txt) do echo %%i
```

The output will be

```
abc %x%
def %y%
```

Is there any (simple) way to get this (without powershell or special executables)?

```
abc 123
def 456
```

Comment: `for /f "delims=" %%i in (textfile.txt) do call echo %%i`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an extra level of calling to evaluate the text string as follows:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set x=123
set y=456
for /f "delims=" %%i in (textfile.txt) do call :evalecho %%i
endlocal
goto :eof

:evalecho
    echo %*
    goto :eof
```

The output of that for you input file is, as requested:

```
abc 123
def 456
```

Comment: Took me some time to remember that you can force a second evaluation with stacked pseudo calls.

Comment: I picked this answer because it was first and I never knew about the "call :label" syntax so it was also additionally educational.

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler way with the call

```
@Echo off
set x=123
set y=456
for /f "delims=" %%i in (textfile.txt) do call call echo %%i
```

A double call is only necessray if there are double percent signs surrounding the var. But they do harm only if you use double percent signs to halt expansion one level.

Comment: my actual solution used "call set" as my actual goal was never to echo the data. I never did try "for...do call call".

Comment: Why two CALLs? A single CALL will do

Comment: @dbenham no, did you test it? I did.

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed that it works as I expected. I took your exact code, removed one CALL, and it continued to work.

Comment: @dbenham Strange, that is opposed to my above added sample. What Windows do you use?

Comment: @LotPings Even for Win10 your described behaviour would be very unexpected, as a `CALL` [restarts the parser at the perecent expansion phase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/how-does-the-windows-command-interpreter-cmd-exe-parse-scripts/4095133#4095133).

Comment: @dbenham,Jeb I have to apologize, I had temporarly doubled the percent signs in the file and forgot about that. So that doubled percent required forced double expansion.